# Grub doesn't show OS selection menu when booting a dual boot setup

Tags: windows, linux, multi-boot, bootloader

I have installed windows and Linux(ubuntu) on the same machine. Now the problem is when I start my machine, It goes directly to Linux and does not ask me for the selection of OS either I want to load Windows or Linux.

How can I change setting that it ask me for the selection of OS?  I guess it is the configuration at bios(machine) level so I asked this question here.

**NOTE:** I want to know settings for both cases either system directly loads Windows or Linux, what will be the settings to make it selected from user.

Comment: NOTE: this specific note has been crossposted to superuser SE!

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I have utilized this, but you would want to research boot loaders.  I know that "grub" is one of the names that comes to mind immediately.  It provides a graphical interface at boot, After post, for a user to select an operating system. If they don't select one, a timeout occurs and a selected default OS is launched.

Answer (score 0):

go to run or search bar in start menu >>> type msconfig >>>> boot tab >>> set your OS boot preferences.

Comment: Right :) and what should I do for Linux as if linux is opening by default? mean where are the boot settings for the Linux

Comment: It's always risky running Linux and Windows side by side. As such, my knowledge and 'experience' is limited in regards to your question. I have always run [Ubuntu live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) off a thumb drive or in a virtual environment via [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). Something to consider if a solution proves difficult to find.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the order of OS's in your /etc/grub/grub.conf file like so:

```
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.32-358.0.1.el6.x86_64)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-358.0.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=UUID=9f61352f-55c5-4063-ba3c-7fde39c04175 
    initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-358.0.1.el6.x86_64.img
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux (2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 ro root=UUID=9f61352f-55c5-4063-ba3c-7fde39c04175 
    initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64.img
```

Also, 'timeout' is the time in seconds the menu waits for you to make a selection.

Answer (score 0):

hope you are using ubuntu latest version,
go to /etc/default and edit file grub you can use any method for editing.use can use this either

`gedit /etc/default/grub`

you will find list of os,

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
```

find the index of your operating system, and replace with x in grub deafult

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=x
```

and finally do a

```
update-grub
```

in your case, i suppose changing time out in  `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by grub not detecting other installed partitions.
To fix this open the grub file

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then enable the os-probe by adding the following line in the grub file

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
```

This will make the os prober detect other bootable partitions.
Save the file and close.

Finally, run
`sudo update-grub`
Restart your pc